# How do I ensure mongod is running with fabric?

Tags: mongodb, fabric

I want to write a fabric task that check is mongod is running and runs it if necessary. Is this possible?

Comment: sure, anything is possible. Do you have any thoughts on how you would solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it on an Ubuntu server using fabric and [fabtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fabtools):

```
from fabric.api import task
from fabtools import require

@task
def setup_mongodb():

    # Install latest official MongoDB package
    require.deb.key('7F0CEB10', keyserver='keyserver.ubuntu.com')
    require.deb.source('mongodb', 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart', 'dist', '10gen')
    require.deb.package('mongodb-10gen')

    # Make sure the server is started
    require.service.started('mongodb')
```

Comment: Is this likely too work on MacOS? I see MacOS isn't explicitly supported by fab tools?